# setTimeout stack over flow

Tags: jquery

> setTimeout stack over flow..
>           
>           
>               $(document).ready(function(){
>                   counterFN();
>
> ```
>             var theCounter = 1;
>             function counterFN()
>             {
>                 $(".searchInput").val(theCounter);
>                 theCounter++;
>                 setTimeout(counterFN(),1000);    
>             }
>
>         });        
>     </script>
> </head>
> <body>
>     <input type="text" class="searchInput" />
> </body> </html>
> ```

Comment: Where is the question? It's more polite to explain your problem with some english, before dumping the problematic code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to clarify what your question is (or it will probably be closed) and also spend some more effort on using the formatting mechanisms for code, click the orange question mark for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling counterFN and setting its return value to run after 1000 milliseconds. Since you aren't returning a function, you probably don't want to do that.

You probably want:

```
            setTimeout(counterFN,1000);
```

Better yet, don't be recursive, and do more caching of things that won't change:

```
        var theCounter = 1;
        var input = $(".searchInput"); // Cache this
        function counterFN()
        {
            input.val(theCounter);
            theCounter++;
        }
        setInterval(counterFN, 1000);
```

Comment: thank you sir.. you got my point without me asking the question.. :) 

setTimeout(counterFN,1000);   really works..

Comment: @user344862: Don't make this a habit. Always clearly describe your problem, not everyone of us likes to go through code and has to *guess* what is wrong. **If you like this answer, *accept* it by clicking on the green tick next to this answer** .

Answer (score 1):

Change this...

```
setTimeout(counterFN(),1000);
```

to this:

```
setTimeout(counterFN,1000);
```

Otherwise, you try to call `counterFN` and set a timeout for whatever it *returns*, instead of setting a timeout for the function itself - but since it tries to call itself before returning (in your original code), this creates an infinite loop of calls, resulting in a stack overflow.